# Linking files through makefiles

Tags: c++, linker, makefile

I have two directories at the same level. I want to use the header file created in one directory in the source file of the other directory. I want to achieve the same without providing relative or absolute path to the header file.

The directory structure is:

```
main_dir/
  dir1/
     main.cpp
     Makefile.am
  dir2/
     abc.h
     abc.cpp
     Makefile.am
```

`main.cpp` needs `abc.h`. What should be written in makefiles of both the directories in order to link them?

**Edit**

Makefile.am of dir2

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libabc.a
AM_CPPFLAG = -I$(main_dir)/dir2 \
     $(APP_CFLAGS)

libabc_a_SOURCES = abc.h \
     abc.cpp
```

Makefile.am of dir1

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libmain.a
AM_CPPFLAG = -I$(main_dir)/dir1 \
     $(APP_CFLAGS)

libmain_a_SOURCES = main.cpp

libmain_a_LIBADD = libabc.a
```

I get the error: `No rule to make target 'libabc.a', needed by 'libmain.a'. Stop.`

Comment: You'll either need to provide the relative/full path of each file, or use something like the [vpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Selective-Search.html) directive.

Comment: By "link them", do you want to make it so `#include <abc.h>` in main.cpp includes main_dir/dir2/abc.h?

Comment: @immibis Yes, I want that!

Comment: @immibis Any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-I` option with gcc or clang. (Note this is not directly related to makefiles)

Example: If the current directory is main_dir, and you're currently running the command:

```
gcc -c -o dir1/main.o dir1/main.cpp
```

you would need to change it to something like:

```
gcc -Idir2 -c -o dir1/main.o dir1/main.cpp
```

Comment: I need to do this in makefile only. I have edited my question. Please check!

Answer (score 0):

You already have

```
AM_CPPFLAG = -I$(main_dir)/dir1 \
     $(APP_CFLAGS)
```

Simply add `-I$(main_dir)/dir2` into it:

```
AM_CPPFLAG = -I$(main_dir)/dir1 \
    -I$(main_dir)/dir2 \
    $(APP_CFLAGS)
```

So now you can `#include <abc.h>` in your code.